# How to know if a File represents a Root or My Computer?

Tags: java, java-io, java.nio.file

I have a `java.io.File` object and i don't know to which it corresponds. Using the `isDirectory()` method we can check whether it is a directory or not. A normal folder and a drive both returns true upon call to `isDirectory()`

How could i check if a `File` object is a drive or My Computer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways, one is

```
File f=new File("C:\\");
if(f.toPath().getNameCount()==0) System.out.println(f+" is root");
```

`getNameCount()` method returns the no. of roots for a given `File`

`toPath()` method returns the `java.nio.file.Path` object for `f`. One more thing, you don't even need to import `java.nio.file` package here.

For instance if `f=new File("C:\\Program Files");` then this returns 1 since there is only one root that is `C:\\`

**A drive gets a name count of 0**

**My Computer cannot be represented as a** `File` **object. If you try to do,**

`File f=new File("C:\\").getParentFile();` you get `null`

Another way is (i dont recommend). Here we will have to use a loop, from performance perspective, it degrades performance and at the same time, this is lengthy as well.

```
File[] files=File.listRoots();
for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
{
  if(files[i].equals(f)){
  System.out.println(f+" is root");
  break;
  }
}
```